# Parsing a HTML table in Perl

Tags: html, perl, html-table, html-parsing

I am trying to parse following HTML table :

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
 <tr bgcolor="#d0d0d0">
  <th style="COLOR: #ff6600">number</th>
  <th style="COLOR: #ff6600">id</th>
  <th style="COLOR: #ff6600">result</th>
  <th style="COLOR: #ff6600">reason</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1027</td>
  <td><a href="<url>">21cs_337</a></td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>catch-all caught </td>
  <td>reason</td>  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>10288</td>
  <td><a href="<url>">21cs_437</a></td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>badfetch</td>
  <td>reason</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to read values from this html file from my perl script. I am using [HTML::TagParser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TagParser) for this and I able to get values for each row:

```
$table_old = ($html_old->getElementsByTagName("tr"))[1]->innerText();
```

But I want to get values for each column (for each row). I tried this:

```
$table_new = ($html_new->getElementsByTagName("tr"))[1];  
my $temp  = ($table_new->getElementsByTagName("td"))[2]->innerText();
```

This doesn't work, any suggestions on how column elements can be parsed efficiently.

Comment: This module might be more suitable: http://search.cpan.org/~djerius/HTML-TableParser-0.40/lib/HTML/TableParser/Table.pm

Comment: Thanks, but I was already using tag parser for most of the other parsing in my script, so was thinking to continue using the same. Looking into Table Parser too, but any suggestions with tag parser might be better.

Comment: [HTML::TableExtract](http://www.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html) is very, very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use subTree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::TagParser;

my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( 'foo.html' ); # Change this to your file

my $nrow = 0;
for my $tr ( $html->getElementsByTagName("tr" ) ) {
    my $ncol = 0;
    for my $td ( $tr->subTree->getElementsByTagName("td") ) {
        print "Row [$nrow], Col [" . $ncol++ . "], Value [" . $td->innerText() . "]\n";
    }
    $nrow++;
}
```

Produces the following output (notice that the th rows are omitted):

```
Row [1], Col [0], Value [1027]
Row [1], Col [1], Value [21cs_337]
Row [1], Col [2], Value [0]
Row [1], Col [3], Value [catch-all caught]
Row [1], Col [4], Value [reason]
Row [2], Col [0], Value [10288]
Row [2], Col [1], Value [21cs_437]
Row [2], Col [2], Value [0]
Row [2], Col [3], Value [badfetch]
Row [2], Col [4], Value [reason]
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but still doesn't help me because i am using perl v5.6.1 which supports HTML-TagParser-0.16 (http://search.cpan.org/~kawasaki/HTML-TagParser-0.16/lib/HTML/TagParser.pm)
and this version doesn't support HTML::TagParser::Element (which is needed for subTree)

Comment: Best advice is to stop using an unsupported version of Perl that is 14 years old. What's preventing you from using a more up to date version?